# What can be deleted to free up storage in SDA?

Tags: cleanup

My SDA is reaching 90%. Can I safety delete files from `/tmp` and `/var/cache/apt/archives` folders based on date, as long as they are not current?

I also tried to remove old Linux Images using both commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.24-24 linux-image-2.6.32-67 
sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-2.6.24-24 linux-image-2.6.32-67
```

But `dpkg` ignored the request saying these images aren't installed, and `apt-get` said it couldn't find these packages.

Which other folders or files can I safety delete?

Comment: Clean the apt cache. `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: SDA is an unclear identifier. Since you are trying to remove old kernel images, do you mean the boot partition? Could you post the output of `df`?

Comment: `/tmp` would not help ... the removed files will return in /tmp/ gradually unless you manually put them there. Missing info: How big is sda?  Did you check /var/log/ for large log files? (anything in /var/log ending on a -digit- can be removed too)

Comment: /var/log do not have large log files. I manage to reduce it down from 90% to 78%. Here's the partial df -h output as it's too long to post:

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             144G  106G   31G  78% /
none                  7.9G  224K  7.9G   1% /dev
none                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
none                  7.9G   64K  7.9G   1% /var/run
none                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /var/lock
none                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /lib/init/rw